# Tensorflow saving and loading

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn how to save and restore models. My model is a little overly complicated, so here is a MWE, straight from command-line python, that produces the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(1, name="var1")
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "testchk.ckpt")
    print "model saved"
```

This format follows the TensorFlow documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1080, in save
self.last_checkpoints, latest_filename)
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 632, in update_checkpoint_state
   file_io.rename(temp_pathname, coord_checkpoint_filename, overwrite=True)
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 79, in rename
compat.as_bytes(oldname), compat.as_bytes(newname), overwrite, status)
  File "/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
self.gen.next()
  File "/mnt/data/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: checkpoint.tmp.fe418ea583db4995810d23d4ca308e3a
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Look like a file system error, does the path exist? Does the program have write access?

Comment: Is it not just the present working directory by default? Yes, it has write access.

Comment: Try using an absolute path?

Comment: Nope. Here's what I did to test write access:
`import os os.access('/path/to/dir', os.W_OK)`
And to try using an absolute path:
`save_path = saver.save(sess, "/path/to/dir/testchk.ckpt")` Naturally, I used my actual path each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the absolute path was not quite the answer, but here's what worked.
In terminal:

```
mkdir test_checkpoint
python
```

Then

```
import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(1, name="var1")
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./test_checkpoint/testchk.ckpt")
    print "model saved"
```

It prints out a bunch of things, then prints: `model saved`

So I think it's working! The directory existed before, so I don't know why creating it anew worked, but at least there's a solution.